# Updating sitecore presentation renderings in standard values messing up the alignment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

Initially my template had the header and footer components in standard values. Internally the header and footer has more than 10 child renderings. Now we have updated the header and footer with a single rendering. As soon as we update our standard values presentation details,  the pages which got created using this template alignment messed up. The first component in the page getting ( should be displayed after the header) messed up. We are using Sitecore7.2. Does anyone faced this similar issue?

Comment: Are you using the same placeholder for your different renderings?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore stores presentation details as an xml text.

Every component is defined by:

```xml
<r 
    uid="{67F55316-B9FD-4902-9BF2-FAAFF1A54ED9}" 
    p:before="r[@uid='{41A67DB2-4FBA-4991-90CC-C9A7D789A6CD}']" 
    s:ds="{BC9968C4-1567-4CC3-BD75-02E4AD6DBDB2}" 
    s:id="{F096F0DF-083C-4EC2-8C0B-EC0500BF8080}"
    s:ph="/main" />
```

Notice that there are `p:before` and `s:ph` attributes.

`s:ph` tells Sitecore in which placeholder the rendering should be placed.

`p:before` tells before which component it should be rendered.

If you add a component to Standard Values item presentation details, it changes the `p:before` of the components on it. And it doesn't know about all the items which uses this Standard Values so it cannot "fix" them.

Also if your item which uses given Standard Values has a component which has `p:before` value set to a component which you removed, Sitecore doesn't know anymore where to put this component.